# how to get runtime width and height of a compundDrawable

Tags: java, android, height, drawable, compound-drawables

I want to know the runtime width and height of a compoundDrawble.

I have tried to use layout inspector, but it shows the height of the text box + drawable.

ViewObserverTree won't help to separate the frawble and the text
to get only the drawable height.

I have also tried `drawable.getBounds()`

but it will give me the compile time height and width.

```
Drawable[] compoundDrawablesRelative = TextViewCompat
    .getCompoundDrawablesRelative(targetTextView);


drawable.getBounds().
```

How would you get the runtime values (in pd and pxl)

Answer (score 0):

```
  Drawable[] drawables = textView.getCompoundDrawables();
  Bitmap myBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawables[1] ).getBitmap();

  //Bitmap myBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable )imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

    int width = myBitmap .getWidth();
    int height = myBitmap .getHeight();
```

try this code

Comment: but is it runtime measurements or not?